# If Bundler installs gems in a non-standard path, how do I get access to those gems and any bin files they come with?

Tags: ruby, capistrano, rvm

I'm deploying a Rails 3 app using Capistrano. I've got RVM running on the remote server (as well as locally) and Bundler is managing all my gems. Here's the issue:

When I deploy, the following command is run by Capistrano:

```
bundle install --gemfile /var/www/releases/20110301225633/Gemfile --path /var/www/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test
```

So, all my gems are in `/var/www/shared/bundle`, okay. But, this means that no gems are installed in the system path (ie, running `gem list` returns nothing), so I can't use any bin files that may have come with those gems, including the `rails` command itself. The only way I've been able to get the web server (thin) started is to manually `gem install thin`. Once thin spools up it starts Rails just fine, including all of its required gems.

So, how do I get access to those gems outside of my running app? I know I shouldn't have to manually install anything to get this to work, but I don't know what I'm missing. I've tried running `rvm-shell '1.9.2@mygemset' -c 'thin start'` but I get the same error as trying to call `thin start` directly from the command line: `bash: thin: command not found` Even going directly to bundler's bin directory `/var/www/shared/bundle/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin` to start thin gives me the same error.

I feel like RVM should be taking care of this for me...maybe there's an environment variable I'm missing?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea behind bundling is that it will install local copies of the gems your project needs without affecting the system-wide gems.

If you want full access to something outside of your rails app, you'll need to manually `gem install` it.

However, if you want to run a bin file for a gem within your project (for example, your `Gemfile` has `gem "thin"` in it and you want to be able to run `thin start` for that project), you can use `bundle exec` and it'll run the bundled version:

```
bundle exec thin start
```

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered this right before seeing this answer!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use:

```
bundle install --path binpaths
```